# Jaxrs (RESTEasy) multiple sub-resources in @Path regexp

Tags: java, regex, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm having a slight issue with using a regex @Path parameter. I'm trying to match path a or b. I've been trying to use:

```
@Path("/{a: path\\/to\\/resource|resource}")
```

So that either

> http://localhost:1111/path/to/resource

or

> http://localhost:1111/resource

would both execute the same method. My issue seems to arise when I use two forward-slashes. I can only access the method using

> http://localhost:1111/resource

but not the other.

However when doing:

```
@Path("/{a: path\\/resource|resource}")
```

It works as intended and I can access the method using

> http://localhost:1111/path/resource

or

> http://localhost:1111/resource.

I have tried doing an negative lookahead to exclude the first part of the query and only return the common property (resource):

```
@Path("/{a: (?!path\\/to\\/)resource}")
```

But that did not work either. It had the same effect as my first implementation, I could only access /resource.

I've also tried:

```
@Path("/{a: (path\\/to)?}{b: (\\/)?}resource")
```

Which worked as intended but also worked if I queried

> http://localhost:1111/path/toresource

or

> http://localhost:1111//resource

Thus creating 4 entry URLs when I want to only have two.

Am I missing something to do with the forward-slashes, why can't my regex pattern contain more than one forward-slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found out the cause of the issue.

I have several other paths with different HTTP methods (GET, PUT, DELETE) using the same URL (/path/to/resource). I suspect that it tried to match path/to/resource against one of those methods before executing the regex. My reasoning for this suspicion is that when I renamed the POST method to:

```
@Path("/{a: (notPath\\/to\\/)?}resource"}
```

It worked as intended. I was able to get a response from both

> localhost:1111/notPath/to/resource

and

> localhost:1111/resource